# "Device is reachable" SMS without SIM

Tags: sms, huawei, sim-card

I'm using a Huawei Honor P9 Lite with a German carrier and SIM card. My carrier offers the option to send SMS to me, whenever I miss a call. The other way round, whenever someone does not reach me (due to missing network connection or powered down phone), they get an SMS as soon as I come back online, telling them that my device is now reachable again.

Now, something very strange happened.
My touchscreen recently broke (I think, due to temperature stress on a very cold day) and I had to send my phone to repair. Before doing that, I removed my SIM card, SD card, backed-up my phone and made a factory reset.

Today, I was contacted by a friend, who tried to reach me during that time by calling me. A day later, he got a message, that I was reachable again. My question now is, how that is even possible with a factory resetted phone without a SIM card? I cannot rule out that the phone has been switched on by the repair contractors, but I wonder how this service actually works without a SIM card and without my number being physically tied to the phone?

Comment: Guessing - you activated call barring and your carrier was authorized. In the process your carrier linked the request with IMEI number and not SIM. You can check with your carrier

Comment: @beeshyams that's a good one, I will check.

Comment: @beeshyams So I just called my carrier and they insisted, that my number is not connected to my IMEI in any way. I will double check the issue once I have my phone back with another mobile phone.

Comment: Another possibility is that your friend himself got a delayed message - delayed because of poor coverage or something

Comment: I can rule that out, because he called me yesterday - 3 days AFTER I took out my SIM card.

Comment: Probably a fault with your carrier's backend which sent a text in error. What you are saying is not possible since SIM is the only thing that tells the phone as to which carrier to connect to and the customer identification. No SIM should mean there was no connection to your number.

Comment: @singhnsk I 100% agree and this is why I asked the question. My next try (as soon as I got my phone back) is (without the SIM in) calling it from another device and then switching it on to see if I can reproduce. If yes, I might need to call ghostbusters ;)

Comment: don't trust carrier 1st-level-support. they are not qualified to know technical information (and they are most likely not employee at that company at all)